# Split up $n \in \mathbb{N}$ into sum of naturals with maximum LCM

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, algorithms, optimization, extremal-combinatorics

**Question**:

Given some natural number, we can of course split it up into various sums of other naturals (e.g. $7 = 6 + 1 = 1 + 4 + 2 = \ldots$)

More precisely, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we can a find distribution sequence (or *partition*) $s_0,\ldots,s_u \in \mathbb{N}$ with

$$\sum_{i=0}^{u}s_i = n$$

Now how can I find the partition $s$ for which the overall least common multiple of all elements is maximal.
Or differently formulated the maximum product of distinct prime factors of all elements.

*Example:*

$$ 7 \mapsto (3, 4); \Pi_{lcm} = 12 $$
$$ 7 \mapsto (1, 2, 4); \Pi_{lcm} = 4$$ 
$$ \ldots $$

Here, the first solution is the desired one.

**Background:**

The background of my question is: How can I split up a sequence/string into contiguous subsequences that, when repeated and [zipped together](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28higher-order_function%29), will yield the longest possible resulting sequence.

For the above example, I could split up a string of length $7$ in the following way:

```
7: abcdefg 7:  abcdefg

    I              II
1: aaaa    3: abcabcabcabc
2: bcbc    4: defgdefgdefg
4: defg
```

Of course, using the second distribution, the resulting sequence has a much greater period.

**So:**

What algorithm/approach can I use to solve this problem and maximize the product? Is this some known problem and how complex would calculating a solution be? It's not NP, I hope?!

**Edit: Partial solution**

As @KennyTM pointed out in the comments, [Landau's function $g$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function) describes the maximum LCM, i.e. $g(7) = 12$.

So this actually becomes: How to actually produce the partition? Does knowledge of $g(x)$ help here, maybe for a dynamic programming solution?

Comment: The LCM values seems to follow [A000793](http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A000793). Edit: Well the definition *is* [Landau's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function).

Comment: @KennyTM: Cool, thanks - Landau's function. Edited the question from this ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blog post here [describes](http://amca01.wordpress.com/2010/07/10/landaus-function/) somebody else's efforts at coding this up. He gets an improvement over the naive approach by using some nice internal structure of the problem.

Comment: Perfect, that was the kind of solution I was looking for. Nice dynamic programming.